# Python replace part of the data in a 4D numpy array with a 2D array using indexing

Tags: python, numpy

If I create a np.zeros array called 'sparsity' of shape (3,1,3,16) and then create a another numpy array of shape (3,16) called 'per_channel_sparsity'.

Is this the correct way to "replace" each of the 3 (3,16) matrices in 'sparsity' with the per_channel_sparsity matrix?

```
import numpy as np

sparsity = np.zeros((3,1,3,16)).astype(np.uint8)
per_channel_sparsity = np.random.rand((3,16)).astype(np.uint8)

for i in range(3):
    sparsity[i, 0, :, :] = per_channel_sparsity
```

Comment: rand generate values between [0, 1) so when you convert it to uint8 they become 0. This is not a very good example. I believe you could do: `sparsity[np.arange(3), 0, :, :] = per_channel_sparsity`

Comment: You can also just do `sparsity[:] = per_channel_sparsity`, since broadcast rules will make it work (the `[:]` is important, it means you are assigning values to the existing array `sparsity`).Or you can just create `sparsity` from `per_channel_sparsity` (without using `np.zeros` first) as `sparsity = np.tile(per_channel_sparsity, (3, 1, 1, 1))`.